# How to connect to SQL Server with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I want to connect to SQL Server with ASP.NET. Can any one give me some sample program to do so?

Comment: Not to be negative, but this seems to be a trivial question to answer through documentation and Googling.

Comment: @Pondlife. you can answer to almost any question by googling :)

Comment: @hgulyan. Absolutely right :-) But this question is so basic that it's just not worth posting here (IMHO).

Comment: @Pondlife, We can't decide that kind of things. We should help everyone who needs it. It's definitely programming related question. That's enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/ASP.NET-SQL-Server.aspx

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

June R's example is inserting data.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

string Connection = "server=ALDAN; uid=sa; pwd=sa; database=GAZCAD; Connect Timeout=10000";

SqlConnection DataConnection = new SqlConnection(Connection);
// the string with T-SQL statement, pay attention: no semicolon at the end of //the statement
string Command = "Select * from myTable";
// create the SQLCommand instance
SQLCommand DataCommand = new SqlCommand(Command, DataConnection);
// open the connection with our database
DataCommand.Connection.Open();
// Data adapter
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(DataCommand);
// To fill data, i need a datatable.
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
// Filling my table
da.Fill(dt);
```